# TV That Supports Direct Casting from Phone Without LAN or Wireless Router Involved

Tags: television

I want to purchase television for someone whose only internet access is via their Android phone. She doesn't even have a wired LAN or a Wireless Router, or any home internet service.

However, I'd like her to be able to cast video from her phone to the TV.

My experience with Casting to a TV has been where there's always a WiFi router (in between the phone and the TV) facilitating that communication. For example, a Chromecast cannot receive video directly from the phone itself (I don't think). Instead the Chromecast must be connected to WiFi, and the phone has to be connected to that same WiFi SSID, then the phone sends video through the wireless router to the Chromecast and then the video ultimately shows on the TV.

Is there a model of TV I can purchase that supports casting of a phone's video directly to the TV without a wireless router as an intermediary?

Comment: You will need a TV with **Miracast** support. Miracast works without a router in the middle. Most Android phones should support Miracast by now.

Comment: Your best bet is to connect from the phone to tv with a cable (usb-hdmi). Miracast can be a bit buggy.

Comment: @Alphy13 I wonder if they make a cable like that, that will also charge the phone while it is connected to the TV.